# im using paging 3 for fetching data from room db the issue im facing is repeating same data and that cause Key was already used

Tags: android, paging

here im fetching AllMessages from Room db

`@Query("SELECT * FROM Message WHERE roomId = :roomId ORDER BY cd DESC limit :pageSize") suspend fun getAllMessage(roomId: Long, pageSize: Int): List<Message>`

here is my PagingSource

`class MessagePagingSource(
private val chatWindowRepository: ChatWindowRepository, private val roomId: Long
) : PagingSource<Int, Message>() {

```
override fun getRefreshKey(state: PagingState<Int, Message>): Int? {
    // We need to get the previous key (or next key if previous is null) of the page
    // that was closest to the most recently accessed index.
    // Anchor position is the most recently accessed index
    return state.anchorPosition?.let { anchorPosition ->
        state.closestPageToPosition(anchorPosition)?.prevKey?.plus(1)
            ?: state.closestPageToPosition(anchorPosition)?.nextKey?.minus(1)
    }

}

override suspend fun load(params: LoadParams<Int>): LoadResult<Int, Message> {
    return try {
        val pageNumber = params.key ?: 0
        val pageSize = params.loadSize
        val response = chatWindowRepository.getMessages(roomId, pageSize)


        LoadResult.Page(
            data = response,
            prevKey = if (pageNumber > 0) pageNumber - 1 else null,
            nextKey = if (response.isNotEmpty()) pageNumber + 1 else null
        )
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.e("itemSnapshotList", "Error loading data: ${e.message}", e)
        LoadResult.Error(e)
    }
}
```

}`

here is my viewmodel side code

`val messages = Pager( config = PagingConfig(pageSize = 10, prefetchDistance = 10), pagingSourceFactory = { MessagePagingSource( chatWindowRepository, roomId = room.roomId ) }).flow.cachedIn(viewModelScope)`

and finally here is my UI side code

`        val list = vm.messages.collectAsLazyPagingItems()

```
    Log.d("itemSnapshotList", "list size is:${list.itemCount}")

    LazyColumn(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(it)
            .fillMaxSize(), reverseLayout = true
    ) {
        items(
            count = list.itemCount,
            key = list.itemKey { message -> message.uuid },
            contentType = list.itemContentType { it.messageType },
            itemContent = {index: Int ->
                val message = list[index]
                Log.d("itemSnapshotList", "uuid is : ${message?.uuid}")
```

}`

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.ainsoft.scoopmessenger, PID: 25528
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Key "1-120+1=1697018154509" was already used. If you are using LazyColumn/Row please make sure you provide a unique key for each item.
at androidx.compose.ui.layout.LayoutNodeSubcompositionsState.subcompose(SubcomposeLayout.kt:433)
at androidx.compose.ui.layout.LayoutNodeSubcompositionsState$Scope.subcompose(SubcomposeLayout.kt:807)
at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.layout.LazyLayoutMeasureScopeImpl.measure-0kLqBqw(LazyLayoutMeasureScope.kt:121)
at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.LazyListMeasuredItemProvider.getAndMeasure(LazyListMeasuredItemProvider.kt:48)
at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.LazyListMeasureKt.measureLazyList-50ZNEM8(LazyListMeasure.kt:181)
at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.LazyListKt$rememberLazyListMeasurePolicy$1$1.invoke-0kLqBqw(LazyList.kt:322)
at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.LazyListKt$rememberLazyListMeasurePolicy$1$1.invoke(LazyList.kt:187)
at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.layout.LazyLayoutKt$LazyLayout$3$2$1.invoke-0kLqBqw(LazyLayout.kt:103)
at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.layout.LazyLayoutKt$LazyLayout$3$2$1.invoke(LazyLayout.kt:96)
at androidx.compose.ui.layout.LayoutNodeSubcompositionsState$createMeasurePolicy$1.measure-3p2s80s(SubcomposeLayout.kt:644)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.InnerNodeCoordinator.measure-BRTryo0(InnerNodeCoordinator.kt:126)
at androidx.compose.ui.graphics.SimpleGraphicsLayerModifier.measure-3p2s80s(GraphicsLayerModifier.kt:646)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.measure-BRTryo0(LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.kt:116)
at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.FillNode.measure-3p2s80s(Size.kt:699)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.measure-BRTryo0(LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.kt:116)
at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.PaddingValuesModifier.measure-3p2s80s(Padding.kt:455)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.measure-BRTryo0(LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.kt:116)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate$performMeasure$2.invoke(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:1560)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate$performMeasure$2.invoke(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:1556)
at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.Snapshot$Companion.observe(Snapshot.kt:2303)
at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver$ObservedScopeMap.observe(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:473)
at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver.observeReads(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:230)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:133)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeMeasureSnapshotReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:113)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.performMeasure-BRTryo0(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:1556)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.access$performMeasure-BRTryo0(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:35)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate$MeasurePassDelegate.remeasure-BRTryo0(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:582)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode.remeasure-_Sx5XlM$ui_release(LayoutNode.kt:1147)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode.remeasure-_Sx5XlM$ui_release$default(LayoutNode.kt:1138)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.doRemeasure-sdFAvZA(MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.kt:331)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.remeasureAndRelayoutIfNeeded(MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.kt:466)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.forceMeasureTheSubtree(MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.kt:546)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.forceMeasureTheSubtree(MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.kt:554)
at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.forceMeasureTheSubtree(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:930)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.Owner.forceMeasureTheSubtree$default(Owner.kt:239)
2023-10-11 15:10:23.929 25528-25528 AndroidRuntime          com.ainsoft.scoopmessenger           E      at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate$MeasurePassDelegate.remeasure-BRTryo0(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:594)

Answer (score 0):

You should chech if size of data is lower than page size (when calculating nextKey). This condition implies that end of pagination is reached and you should not load data.
For some reason it fetches some more elements if page size is lower.